# REST API & Ember (data) - Many-to-Many relation with attributes

Tags: json, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I have two resources in my system **users** and **organizations**.
Each has a name and a relation with the other (many to many).

In my REST API I have:

> /organizations - returns all organizations in the system (public)
>
> /users         - return all users in the system (public)

After this I needed to add properties to the relation (e.g. role in the organization). For this I created the concept of worker, a person in an organization.

What I have tried:

- A new model, a "full resource"; it doesn't comply with a good rest design.
- A nested resource inside organizations; better in json, but in Ember using EmbeddedRecordsMixin I lose the ability to manipulate the model - e.g. usage of adapter or serializer to change the resource.

**How to design the REST api?**

**How to define Ember models and how to manipulate them?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Suggest making a 3rd resource that contains the role properties and relations to user and organization
2. You can use links, an example response for an organization:

   ```
   {
       id: 1,
       links: {
           users: "/organizations/1/users"
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would you include the 3rd resource in your example? You are just relation organization and user..